# How to get two column references with author-year style

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, natbib

Is there a way to get a two column layout for author-year-citations with a label of "(Wolfram 2002)" in the first column and "Wolfram, S. 2002. A new kind of science. Wolfram Media, Champaign, Ill." in the second column.

The best I could get is the label directly followed by the reference with indentation in the following lines; with something I found, but not quite understand:

```
\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}

\makeatletter
       \def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
       \if\relax\@extra@b@citeb\relax\else
       \@ifundefined{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{}{%
       \@namedef{br@#2}{\@nameuse{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}}}\fi
       \@ifundefined{b@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{\def\NAT@num{}}{\NAT@parse{#2}}%
       \item[\hfil\hyper@natanchorstart{#2\@extra@b@citeb}\citep{#2}%
       \hyper@natanchorend]%
       \NAT@ifcmd#1(@)(@)\@nil{#2}}
\makeatother
```

I am using Bibtex and pdflatex. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want a single column article with references starting on a new page in two-column mode?

Comment: No just like the numbered or alphanumeric styles with label in the first column and the reference in the second column.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for one text column and one citation column. This can be achieved using the margin and biblatex.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{%
(\cite{#1})%
\marginpar{\footnotesize\fullcite{#1}}}
```

If this is what you are looking for[image: citation in the margin]

I used the following code (partly borrowed from another question):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=40pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Baauw2001,
    Address = {Somerville, MA},
    Author = {Sergio Baauw},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 25th Annual Boston University Conference on Language Development},
    Editor = {A. H.-J. Do and L. Dom{\'\i}nguez and A. Johansen},
    Pages = {82-93},
    Publisher = {Cascadilla Press},
    Title = {Expletive determiners in child Dutch and Spanish},
    Year = {2001}}

@article{barker1998,
    Author = {Chris Barker},
    Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    Pages = {679-717},
    Title = {Partitives, Double Genitives and Anti-Uniqueness},
    Volume = {16},
    Year = {1998}}

@book{Berwick1985,
    Address = {Cambridge, MA},
    Author = {Berwick, Robert C.},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {Acquisition of syntactic knowledge},
    Year = {1985}}

@phdthesis{Carlson1977,
    Author = {Carlson, Gregory N.},
    School = {University of Massachusetts, Amherst},
    Title = {Reference to Kinds in {E}nglish},
    Year = {1977}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{%
(\cite{#1})%
\marginpar{\footnotesize\fullcite{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[2]Some text \mycite{Carlson1977}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several author-year bibliography styles that have the label followed by the author in the order you want.  [Ken Turner's list of older Bibtex styles](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html) shows several possibilities.  Most of these use the `\bibhang` dimension (actually it is skip, so you can have glue) to control indentation, so you can replicate what the code you quote appears to be doing by choosing any of these styles and setting `\bibhang` to a large enough dimension.  The others use `\bibindent` and `\bibleftmargin` to say what the first and each subsequent line of the entries are respectively, which is equivalent.

This is not exactly what your question describes, since the author name follows directly after the key.  You can force enough whitespace by putting the label in a wide-enough box.  You have to tinker with the Bibtex style code to do this.  With luck, the following code will work for you:

```
\makeatletter 
   \let\ur@lbibitem=@lbibitem
   \def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{
       \ifempty{#1}
           \ur@lbibitem[\hbox to \bibhang {#2}]{#2}
         \else \ur@lbibitem[\hbox to \bibhang {\cite{#1}}]{#2}
       \fi}
\makeatother
```

Caveats: the above is untested, need the eplain package (it uses `\ifempty`), will probably be ugly (the hbox will be too wide and `\cite` is quite probably the wrong command for what you want), and assumes that `\bibhang` is correctly defined which is not true for all Bibtex styles.

Comment: I somehow can't get it work. I could use '\setlength{\bibhang}{10em}' but that results in the first line of the reference beginning dependent on the label and not at a specific position. Many times in different combinations I also tried the code you cited, but it gave me errors that I could not get rid of. I also have fount the Turner's list, and 'these' is very similar to my desired result, but when I use it it results in a label like '[W]' and I also wanted to use the 'natbib' package.